# FCM Cloud Messaging Report only shows "Sends"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, analytics, web-push

We have implemented WebPush Notification with FCM for WEB. The system works fine. But when you want to see the statistics in the Firebase console (Cloud Messaging -> Report) only the number of "Sends" is modified.
"Open count" records changes but not always.
"Received" and "Impressions" is always at 0. It is possible to register this for WEB? The documentation says only Android and iOS but it is not clear to us if it refers to native apps.

Following the documentation, we add "measurementId" to the config and initialize firebase.analytics(). Supposedly with this it should only automatically record the events that we are requesting but it is not working. We already let more than 24 hours pass and nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding sth to "Label" when you compose a notification on the Firebase console.